# Building release Android APK with vs-android

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, release, vs-android

I have a large amount of C++ native code and a small wrapping java code for Android application. I was able to combine them into an Android app using vs-android and build it directly from Visual Studio 2012. 
But I can do this only in DEBUG mode. In RELEASE - ant complains that I need a key to sign the app. 
**What do I need to do in order to be able to build RELEASE app and deploy it to device automatically (as done in DEBUG mode)?**

By the way, I want to build a RELEASE just to see how fast the C++ code runs and not for publishing the application on Google store. So If there is a way to inject the key which is used in DEBUG mode also for RELEASE that would be great.

A solution I don't want to receive: Run a build that creates un-signed APK, and than call a batch file that adds signature, zipalligns, etc...
I want everything to run smoothly when hitting the 'build' button in Visual Studio.

Another bad solution is using Ecllipse. I want to use visual studio.

Please help

Comment: I believe only Eclipse and Android Studio are the official tools. So, it can happen that your desire remains unsatisfied. Although maybe someone does use VS. What's so special about VS?

Comment: Have you considered just replacing your debug keystore with a release key (sans password)?

Comment: Impossible. There is no debug keystore of "mine" since ant does that. It is created during the build. I know that the solution to this problem should be easy but I don't know it.   P.s. - The special thing in VS-android is that I can build android apps from visual studio

Comment: Whoever down voted my question, please explain, why. This is a valid question and my Answer is also valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution:

1. Go to the directory of ANT build.xml inside Android SDK.
   Mine was here: C:\android_sdk\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\sdk\tools\ant
   The build.xml file is rather large (about 70kb). Open this file for editing.
2. Find the line `<target name="-release-nosign" unless="has.keystore">`
3. Add the following properties bellow:

`<property name="has.keystore" value="true" />`

`<property name="key.store" value="release.keystore" />`

`<property name="key.store.password" value="android" />`

`<property name="key.alias"          value="androiddebugkey" />`

`<property name="key.alias.password" value="android" />`

1. Finaly, go to the directory of the APK you are trying to compile, You should already have debug.keystore file. Just copy it and rename it release.keystore

Answer (score 1):

Run keytool and create a keystore, for example

`C:\my-project\my-release-keystore.keystore`

then in the same directory as your project.properties add an ant.properties with the following:

```
key.store=C:\\my-project\\my-release-keytore.keystore
key.store.password=my-keystore-password
key.alias=my-apps-alias
key.alias.password=my-alias-password
```

That's it - when you build release mode ANT will sign your release APK.